# Deleted the Row in Session by mistake

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am beginner in android and parse.com .I had created a parse user. Then I have deleted session from parse application by mistake. Now when I try to create a user is says $Parse Request Exception:Invalid Session Token.
Is there any way how I can fix it??? Please Help

Comment: Have you tried login into your app again? that should re-create your session token

Comment: No. I logged in my parse app again and again. but no session token created. Do I have to create new app in parse.com now?

Comment: did you delete the session object from the data browser?

Comment: I have deleted my parseUser object by calling deleteInBackground() . Now I  have changed the name of the previous Parseuser object and trying to create new parseuser. Still I am finding the same problem.

Comment: in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/30855061/113608 the user managed to login after uninstalling the apk and loading it again.